# My background image not showing on live review using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried lots of different ways and nothing is showing up, I never use Brackets environment and I'm facing this issue. I added my URL image background but it isn't showing up. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Comment: Try using only `background-image: url("sawir1.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the url is wrong, you are in the folder image so you just have to write it like this :

`background-image: liner-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6), url(sawirl.jpg))`